# cocos2d, how to upscale images automatically for iPad

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I was wondering if there is a way to upscale image automatically for iPad and if so how. Or if it is recommended to do individual images how do I make cocos2d recognized iPad images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following extension for image.

```
background.png   - for iPhone SD (480x320 )
background-hd.png   - for iPhone HD (960x640 )
background-ipad.png   - for iPad ( 1024x768 )
background-ipadhd.png   - for iPad ( 2048x1536 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Upscaling images is not recommended. For the simple reason that you won't gain any quality (in fact, you'll lose some). Scaling on the fly via scale property can be done, but again you lose quality and in this case also performance.

Instead, use a tool like TexturePacker, design your images in the highest possible resolution and allow TexturePacker to handle the export and downscaling (that's ok) of your assets to the lower resolutions.

Raj already answered the file suffixes.